# lateinit var for LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, race-condition

In my ViewModel I have a `lateinit var` to hold some LiveData. The way this variable is initialized depends on the data and the current date. Can't do it in SQL. This is the ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel {
    lateinit var timeStamps: LiveData<List<TimeStamp>>

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val db = RoomDB.getInstance(application).timeStampDao()
            val lastTimeStamp = db.getLast()
            if (lastTimeStamp == null
                || (lastTimeStamp.instant < setToStartOfDay(Calendar.getInstance()).timeInMillis)
                && lastTimeStamp.action == ACTION.END_WORK) {
                timeStamps = db.getAllAfterLive(Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis)
            } else {
                db.getLastAction(ACTION.START_WORK)?.let { lastStartWork ->
                    val startOfDay = setToStartOfDay(initCalendar(lastStartWork.instant)).timeInMillis
                    db.getFirstActionAfter(ACTION.START_WORK, startOfDay)?.let {
                        timeStamps = db.getAllAfterLive(it.instant)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here I access `timeStamps` in my Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    viewModel.timeStamps.observe(this) { list -> recordsAdapter.submitList(list) }
```

This leads to a `UninitializedPropertyAccessException`: onCreate runs faster than the `timeStamps` initialization launched in parallel.

I fixed this by introducing another `lateinit var` for a callback:

```
class MainViewModel {
    lateinit var timeStamps: LiveData<List<TimeStamp>>
    lateinit var timeStampsInitializedCallback: () -> Unit

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // inspect the data and initialize timeStamps
            timeStampsInitializedCallback()
        }
```

which I initialize in `onCreate`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    viewModel.timeStampsInitializedCallback = {
        viewModel.timeStamps.observe(this) { list -> recordsAdapter.submitList(list) }
    }
```

This works, but it introduces a race condition. Should the initialization for `timeStamps` unexpectedly finish before the callback is initialized, I'd get another `UninitializedPropertyAccessException` and be back where I started.

How can I improve this code?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this anyway - a `LiveData` with no initial value in the constructor is "empty", and anything that `observe`s it won't get a callback until a value is pushed to the `LiveData`. You can just wire it up, and things will react to values and events when they happen. CommonsWare's answer is the typical way to set them up, and it should work for what you're doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [`liveData`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata) builder function:

```
class MainViewModel {
    val timeStamps: LiveData<List<TimeStamp>> = liveData {
        // inspect the data and initialize timeStamps
        emit(timeStamps) // emit list of TimeStamps
        emitSource(liveData) // emit another LiveData
    }

}

// in Activity

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    viewModel.timeStamps.observe(this) { list -> recordsAdapter.submitList(list) }
}
```

The `liveData` code block starts executing when `LiveData` becomes active and is automatically canceled after a configurable timeout when the `LiveData` becomes inactive.

Comment: `emit()` expects `List<TimeStamp>`, not `LiveData<List<TimeStamp>>`. I think this is not what I want. I've updated my question to show what I'm actually doing.

Comment: @user1785730 please check my updated answer. You can call `emitSource` function to emit another `LiveData` object.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option seems like `MutableLiveData`:

```kotlin
class MainViewModel {
    private val _timeStamps = MutableLiveData<List<TimeStamp>>()
    val timeStamps: LiveData<List<TimeStamp>> = _timeStamps

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // inspect the data and set a value on _timeStamps
        }
```

Depending on what the coroutine is doing, there may be other options (e.g., `asLiveData()` on a `Flow`, `MediatorLiveData`).

Comment: When I set up `timeStamps` this way, will `timeStamps` update observers due to updates in the database?

Comment: @user1785730: I do not know what database you are referring to. But, if you call `_timeStamps.postValue()`, that value will be delivered to active observers.

Comment: That is not what I want to do. After the initial logic to figure out the data I want `timeStamps` to be wired to the database. I've updated my question with the code of what I'm actually doing.

Comment: There are two cases: in both cases I assign to `timeStamps` LiveData from the database.

Comment: @user1785730: You could use `MediatorLiveData`. Frankly, having a Room DAO return `LiveData`, in an app where you are already using coroutines, does not seem like a great solution. If you have your Room DAO return `Flow`, you would have more options.